# How to allocate memory to const char* class member in member initialization list

Tags: c++

How to allocate memory to `const char*` class member in member initialization list?

```
class A {
    const char *member;
public: 
    A(const char *m);
}

A::A(const char *m):member(m) {
//I want to allocate memory to member in member initialization list
}
```

Comment: In C style strings memory is typically allocated using `(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*lengthOfString)`

Comment: If there are not secret rules forcing you to use a pointer, I would use `std::string   member` and get rid of all allocation problems.

Comment: @apokryfos: That's completely wrong for C++. And even in C,  `sizeof(char)` is redundant because it's always 1.

Comment: @ChristianHackl even if it is redundant it's generally good practice in case future implementations decide to change the size of the character.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
class A 
{ 
    const char *member; 
public: 
    A(const char *m); 
};

A::A(const char *m) : member( new char[std::strlen( m ) + 1] ) 
{ 
    std::strcpy( member, m );
}
```

Take into account that the data member `member` is not a constant itself.

Or you can even write the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

struct A
{
    const char *s;
    A( const char *s ) : s( std::strcpy( new char[std::strlen( s ) + 1], s ) )
    {
    }

    ~A() 
    { 
        delete [] s;
    }       
};

int main()
{
    A a( "Hello, World!" );

    std::cout << a.s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One should also mention the Rule of Three or its C++11 adaption.